# Manipulating dates into time-series using Excel

Tags: excel, time-series, vba

I have two worksheets with 78 columns in each and 365 rows. The first worksheet has dates and the second worksheet has values. I would like to take the columns and then place them in alternating order in a new worksheet. So column A from worksheet 1 and then column A from worksheet 2 and so. So there would be 156 total columns.

After that, I would like to take another column of 78 dates that I have in another worksheet and designate it as 0. Then I need to create a column to the left of each of the 78 value columns and have that column contain numbers from `t = -n` to `t = m` where `n` is the number of rows above the `t = 0` date and `m` is equal to the number of value after the `t = 0` date. Essentially I am trying to convert the dates which are different all different into something uniform which I can then use for the purpose of time-series analysis and graphing.

The last step is to move each triplet of columns so that the `t = 0` dates are in the same row across the 78 triplets of columns. All of the cell contents are values, not formulas.

Comment: Attempting to write code, will post when finished.

Comment: Would it be possible to show me how to do it? This is the only time that I will be doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't go into detail at present but would be happy to adjust later (a few days?) if necessary. Working on a copy:

1. Insert a row at the top of the `dates` sheet and copy the 'another sheet` dates into it (with transposition).
2. Copy your 'values' sheet below your 'dates`.
3. Insert two columns every other column (tedious - but a macro for this would be simple!)
4. Shunt the 'values' across to the right one column.
5. Select entire sheet, Home > Editing - Find & Select, Go To Special, Blanks.
6. Right-click a select cell, Delete..., Shift cells up.
7. Add a column on the extreme left.
8. In A2 put `=IFERROR(1-MATCH(B$1,B2:B$366,0),ROW()-MATCH(B$1,B$2:B$366,0)-MATCH(B$1,B$1:B$366,0))`
9. Copy A2 down and into D2, G2 etc (also copying down).

There will be more efficient ways of getting to this point but I hope it may at least give you some ideas.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll try it out. I'll let you know of the results.

Comment: Thanks for the above solution, it worked on the data that I had. However, I am not sure on how align the triplets of columns. If you could help, I would truly appreciate it.

Comment: ^ That wouldn't work but I wrote VBA code to move the triplets anyway. Thanks for your help.